# Storyboard segue hides tabBarButton on destination view

Tags: ios, storyboard

Sorry for bad english.
I have `MainViewController` and `TabBarController` with two Views in storyboard.
when i push button (using modal segue) in my `MainviewController` - app switch to `firstTabBarView` or `secondTabBarView` depending on conditions. it works fine but after that i lost my `TabBarControls` at the bottom of any of my tabBarViews.

UPD: action after bar Button pressed

```
-(IBAction)barButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (condition !=0 ) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:nil];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing us the relevant code always helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's working as advised. A modal segue is a "fullscreen segue" and covers your standard navigation stack. 
If you simply want to change the selected viewcontroller, use

```
[yourTabBarControllerInstance setSelectedIndex:index];
```

Comment: my noobnes didnt allow me to understand how did i get "yourTabBarControllerInstance" if i created it in storyboard

Comment: I'm writing from iPhone now and not sure about the exact syntax. You have to go through: Application, delegate, main window, root view controller. It should  be UITabBarController *tb = (UITabBarController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];